# Flutter: memory access out of bounds

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, segmentation-fault

I am using latest stable Flutter and have a minimal app which I run in web (Chrome). After pressing some specific buttons app hangs and after some time Chrome shows message about SIGSEGV caught. When running as web server I can spot this message in console but it does not give me more information

> Another exception was thrown: RuntimeError: memory access out of
> bounds

How to catch what is crashing?

After some investigations I have found that crash happens when this custom component is used. But I do not see any suspicious code.

```
class RotationMatrixTransformation extends StatelessWidget {
  RotationMatrixTransformation({
    this.dyOffset,
    this.childComponent,
  });

  final Widget? childComponent;
  final dyOffset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
          ..rotateX(0.01 * dyOffset),
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: childComponent
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Flutter? There was an issue with a similar error , check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80140

Comment: Should be on latest (Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable ). Do you know how to figure out if fix for the issue you mentioned is included in the release?

Comment: The issue is gone after I updated to 2.4.0-4.2.pre . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me the issue was gone after updating to 2.4.0-4.2.pre